# Selecting input value in modal window

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to select an input field's value inside modal window.

```
function title()
{
  $('a.title_filestock').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data   = $(this).children('img').attr('rel');
    var active = $(this).next('a.filestock_preview');
    var value  = active.text();
    new VayesModal('<label for=Display Name"><input id="'+data+'" type="text" size="12" value="'+$.trim(value)+'" />', { modal: true, modalOpacity: '.5', title: 'Type File Display Name', titleClass: 'anim warning', buttons: [{id: 0, label: 'Save', val: 'Y', btnClass: 'btn-success'}, {id: 1, label: 'Cancel', val: 'N', btnClass: 'btn-danger'}], callback: function(val) { if(val == 'Y') { alert($('input[id="'+data+'"]').val()); active.text('new string');  } else return false; }});
  });
}

title();
```

"new string" should be `$('input[id="'+data+'"]').val()` but it returns undefined. I might make a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem is, that 
callback:function(val) {
  dont have access to local "data" variable (defined) from function title()
  try alert(data) and this will be also undefined.

try what console.log($(this))    will returns, because this must be any parent object (probably some ModalWindow object) and maybe you can add "data" variable into this and load from in callback
}

I didnt found any existing VayesModal library on google, so I cant help you more.
Try http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form

little hint:
$('input[id="'+data+'"]')   equals to   $('input#"'+data)

EDIT:
Found it :) Callback is called after modal window is removed, so input doesnt exists yet. Go to messi.js, method 
Messi.prototype.hide(after) { and move ""if (after) after.call(); "" to first line in this.messi.animate...function, before .remove() }
BUT keep in mind, that you changed plugin source code.
(VayesModal is Messi plugin. )

Comment: Thanks fy reply. I can alert(data) correctly in callback. VayesModal is an alias for messi pluging [https://github.com/marcosesperon/Messi]  Hope this helps you to help me. And thanks for great hint.

Comment: Found it :)
Callback is called after modal window is removed, so input doesnt exists yet.
Go to messi.js, method Messi.prototype.hide(after) {
    and move  ""if (after) after.call(); ""  to first line in this.messi.animate...function,  before .remove()
}

Comment: Works in charm. Please add this to your original answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Try `alert($('input[id="'+data+'"]').length)`. It should be zero as I think that your input element is still not loaded in the modal and you are already trying to access that.

Comment: Yes, it returns zero as you said. How can I fix this?

Comment: I am trying to access when I was clicked Save inside the modal window.

Comment: First you need to confirm whether you actually were able to append the input box into your modal. Inserting a new input box in DOM will take split seconds. Is your VayesModal doing it correctly. Or may be VayesModal is creating an iframe and inside that populating the content. Thats why you were not able to access input box directly. DO check how VayesModal is getting the modal window.

Comment: I think it is not the problem: `<div class="vayesModal-content" style="padding: 10px; height: auto; "><label for="Display Name"><input id="article-1-22" type="text" size="12" value="sometext"></label></div>` It looks in DOM and not iframe.

Comment: replace `alert($('input[id="'+data+'"]').val());` with `alert($('#'+data).val());`

Comment: undefined. I guess I figured out the reason of the problem. It is a callback for SAVE button click, so press SAVE, it removes modal and there is not input field in DOM. But couldn't figure out the solution.

Comment: there must be some way to call the function before closing the modal. You'll find the solution within the vayesmodal js plugin file.

Comment: Please see @Josef Zajac 's answer if interested. Thank you for your help.

Comment: perfect solution. I told you that there was something with the plugin. and @Josef found it.